# Why is the Chrome Developer Tools interface cropping my page?

Tags: css, google-chrome

This doesn't seem to be a common problem as I haven't found anything related. Chrome(Chromium in my case) DevTools seems to be behaving strange for me. It is cropping the right side of my page. Firefox DevTools does not do this. After restarting Chromium, it is now cropping even more. I tried changing the zoom and resolution. 
[image]

Comment: Questions regarding the [usage of web browsers and other software not directly related to running your own website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask this, but I'd suggest adding the version and OS that you're using first.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it by choosing a device in the drop down menu. Still not sure why it was doing that.

Comment: Possibly differences in the Device Pixel Ratio (DPR) - CSS Pixel vs Device Pixel?